# Is there a way to insert a link in a Facebook image description?

Tags: facebook, images, embed, links

Is there any way I can embed a link in Facebook image description?
I tried `<a href>` and `[alt](link)` tag, but it encoded it and showed the tag itself.

I want the link to be hidden by a word.
A simple link is allowed.

Is there any other way?

What about embedding the link and only show the text (applies to any post type in facebook)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible to use special formatting in Facebook Photos.

Consider using a url shortener and vanity name for your links if you do not like the way they are presented.

e.g shrt.io/test

Otherwise, use [Facebook Notes](http://www.facebook.com/notes/phwd/facebook-notes-cheat-sheet/307472899342741) instead.

[image: Cheat Sheet]